# Different logic in one stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: performance, delphi, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I need your help to one strategic question in my programing for database.

I work in Delphi 2010 and SQL Server 2012. Components Sdac for access to database. I quite often use a stored procedure for very many often absolutely different tasks. Fortunately SQL Server allows different result sets from one stored procedure.

I have a parameter `@Wmode int` (and several others too) and each value of wmode is separate task. Some of this are heavy other not, some have quite a lot of code some very few.

I use this approach because I try to put as much logic of application in code of stored procedures because at least for me its much easier to make any modifications, to test, debug, to set logs or to execute separately of my application.

Tell me please how much this approach can affect a performance this requests to database and how i can improve it. Is it better for me to use such approach only to seldomly executing parts of application. Can you give some links read on this subject.

Comment: If a single stored procedure contains very different logic, based on an external parameter, chances are it will **NOT** perform very well - except for one of the "modes". The "mode" that you run the first query for will define the execution plan that stored procedure puts into cache, and reuses on subsequent executions - even if they are for a totally different code logic. This is ***NOT*** a very smart idea at all !

Comment: The **Single Responsibility Principle** should be used here, too - one stored procedure should do **one thing** and **one thing only** (and do it well). If you have three or five different tasks / logics - use just as many stored procedures, so that each can do its job as best it can

Comment: I would suggest **not** doing this - SQL Server & t-sql is *not* a traditional programming language like Java or c# and many common coding paradigms simply do not apply or work well here. A stored procedure should ideally be as concise as possible and focus on one specialised use-case for best performance, trying to do too much in a single procedure can lead to unexpected recompilations and many other performance issues.

Comment: "Fortunately SQL Server allows different result sets from one stored procedure." or rather unfortunately IMO, as your case shows. Do not do this. One task, one procedure.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I already had such suspensions, and  events suggested your ideas. I will continue to get rid of such practice in all important and sensitive parts.

Comment: This approach of course decreases quality of application little bit but it accelerates my coding quite significantly. Especially with using live templates in Delphi and inherited classes in it. In standard task to show any information in user interface with all this can be ten times faster probably than without

Comment: Don't see the savings. Doing  `SomeProcedure(XXX)` vs `SomeProcedureXXX()` doesn't  really save anything on the Delphi side and makes the SQL side more error prone as too much code is stuffed into one procedure.

Comment: List of stored procedures in database becames larger and more heavy. It is quite large in our main databases already. Most of my colleagues and my senior too searching in this list in ssms manually and i can imagine it's hard and irritating. I almost never search such way i have my special universal stored proc for it but i am afraid it could start to be slowly if this quantity became too much